# Jasper report : force summary band to the bottom of the page

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I force the summary band to be at the bottom of the page and not right below the detail band?

Comment: What about using page footer band?

Comment: or last page footer, if only on last page, see [Understanding the different report bands](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/3594/getting-started-with-jasper-reports/14657/understanding-the-different-report-bands#t=2017062008004110475) for more information

Comment: in the summary, I am displaying a variable that is the sum of a detail values int the entire report. If I put them in a footer or last footer band, I think that the variable will be the sum of the detail values of the current page.

Answer (score 3):

Use the special band "Last Page Footer"

Click add band on the left panel. It should be faded below the "Page Footer" band.

Comment: Minor note, this will replace the default footer with the last page footer. So if you need the this band above the regular footer, this solution is not ideal

Comment: @Draken What is then Ideal? This is the only solution i've found, but I've just doubled the "normal" page footer to also be in the last page footer...

Comment: @AndersMetnik I don't believe there is an ideal solution in this case. My comment was to point out that it does solve some instances, but has its limitations.